# Subset Question Dealing with Subsets With One element or Less

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

How many subsets of a set with $100$ elements have more than one element?

I know that a set, $S$, has $100$ elements, $|S| = 100$, and that all the subsets from $S$ is $2^{100}$, but how do I know how many subsets have one element? I know one is the empty set.

Comment: 1) The empty set has zero elements. 2) Assume $S$ is the set of numbers from 1 to 100. Can you list some subsets that have one element?

Comment: The empty set does **not** have one element: it has **no** elements. There is one one-element subset for each element of $S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total subsets $-$ singleton sets $-$ empty set:

$2^{100} - 100 - 1$.